# How to correct test for unicode strings with Django and Python 2

Tags: python, django, testing, unicode

I need to test, whether the representation of my Django models are working with Unicode as it might be that users insert th9ings like ü or ¼ into it. To do so, I have this Django tests.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.test import TestCase
from django.utils import timezone

from .models import *
from .views import *

class CategoryTestCase(TestCase):
    """ Test to check whether category name is printed correctly.
        If there is a parent, it should be also printed seperated by a : """

    def setUp(self):
        self.cat1 = Category.objects.create(name=u'Category 1')
        self.cat2 = Category.objects.create(name=u'Category ü', parent=self.cat1)
        self.cat3 = Category.objects.create(name=u'Category 3', parent=self.cat2)

    def test_category_name(self):
        cat_result1 = u'Category 1'
        cat_result2 = u'Category 1' + settings.PARENT_DELIMITER + u'Category ü'
        cat_result3 = u'Category 1' + settings.PARENT_DELIMITER + u'Category ü' + settings.PARENT_DELIMITER + u'Category 3'
        self.assertEqual(self.cat1.__str__(), cat_result1)
        self.assertEqual(self.cat2.__str__(), cat_result2)
        self.assertEqual(self.cat3.__str__(), cat_result3)
```

This is intended to test this little model:

```
#...
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
#....
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Category(models.Model):
    """ Representing a category a part might contains to.
    E.g. resistor """

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        help_text=_("Name of the category.")
    )
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        "self",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text=_("If having a subcateogry, the parent.")
    )
    description = models.TextField(
        _("Description"),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text=_("A chance to summarize usage of category.")
    )

    def __str__(self):
        if self.parent is None:
            return ('{}'.format(self.name))
        else:
            return ('%s%s%s' % (
                self.parent.__str__(),
                settings.PARENT_DELIMITER,
                self.name)
            )

    def get_parents(self):
        """ Returns a list with parants of that StoragePare incl itself"""
        result = []
        next = self
        while True:
            if next.id in result:
                raise(CircleDetectedException(
                    _('There seems to be a circle inside ancestors of %s.' % self.id)))
            else:
                result.append(next.id)
                if next.parent is not None:
                    next = next.parent
                else:
                    break
        return result

    def clean(self):
        pass
```

(stripped that a little)

When running this code via Python 3 and test or with Python2/3 executing as application it's working. Only the test with Python2 is failing so I assume it's something wrong with my idea how to test this. Based on the error message it appears that the Unicode string is somewhere not properly encoded and decoded.

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_category_name (partsmanagement.tests.CategoryTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/frlan/quellen/partuniverse/partuniverse/partsmanagement/tests.py", line 31, in test_category_name
    self.assertEqual(self.cat2.__str__(), cat_result2)
AssertionError: 'Category 1->Category \xc3\xbc' != u'Category 1->Category \xfc'
```

So my question is: How to do proper Unicode-representation testing with Django.

Comment: If you are using python 2, your models should have a `__unicode__` method instead of `__str__`, and that method should return a unicode object [(docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/unicode/#choosing-between-str-and-unicode).  You can use `from __future__ import unicode_literals` in your django code to make it cross-compatible between python 2 and 3. [(docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/unicode/#general-string-handling)

Comment: The decorator pretends to do so on model-side. And in fact it appears to work as the application is running. But on tests having Python 2 and checking on __str__() is not working as well as __unicode__() is failing.

Comment: `'Category 1->Category \xc3\xbc'` is a utf-8 encoded python 2 string. Why don't you just use unicode objects everywhere? This is explained in the documentation I linked to in my previous comment. You should read the entire page if you want to write code that works in both python 2 and 3.

Comment: Might be a dump, but trying to apply the documentation forces me to create__str__() and __unicode__() with same content on Python 2 even the document say just create __unciode__(). Same error as above. Also it feels wrong to use Bytestring coded UTF when I want to test real UTF.

Comment: You test will not pass as long as you compare utf-8 encoded strings with real unicode. You could just decode. `'\xc3\xbc'.decode('utf-8') == u'\xfc'`

Comment: Why/where this is happening? Or maybe the better question: Why I put real Unicode in and only get some encoded one out?

Comment: Read you error message.

Comment: In python 2, the `Model.__str__()` method will encode unicode as utf-8. This is explained in the docs. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/unicode/#choosing-between-str-and-unicode

Comment: ``self.assertEqual(self.cat1.__str__(), cat_result1.decode('utf-8'))`` is failing too. I would be happy to award a working answer with  some extra reutation

Comment: you got it the wrong way around. It's the `str` that must be decoded. `self.cat1.__str__().decode('utf-8') == cat_result1`. Or you can encode the unicode. `self.cat1.__str__() == cat_result1.encode('utf-8')`. This might also work. `self.cat1.__unicode__() == cat_result1`. Or this `u"{}".format(self.cat1) == cat_result1`

Comment: @HåkenLid All your four concrete  comments are OK in Python 2, but would fail in Python 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl; dr ) **Use the same type on both sides of assertEqual**.

The best code, universal for Python 3 and 2 is possible without adding symbols like `u'', unicode, foo.__str__()` etc. Less code should be written and more thought about both what type is expected where in Python 2/3.

**part A) fix the test**

A short (ugly) solution is to use text_type on the left side if you use the same explicit type `u'...'` on the right side. Avoid to use functions with underscores due to better readability. You can convert a value to text_type by several ways:

Replace the line in test by

```
self.assertEqual(u'%s' % self.cat1, cat_result1)
```

or

```
self.assertEqual(u'{}'.format(self.cat1), cat_result1)
```

or

```
from django.utils.six import text_type
self.assertEqual(text_type(self.cat1), cat_result1)
```

A nicer solution is to unify the type in your module and to use `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the beginning of your module because you work mostly with texts not with binary data. Than you can remove all `u'`, but it is still useful until everything works in both versions.

**part B) fix the `__str__` method**

Your code would fail if both the parent category name and the current name are not in ASCII. Fix:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
# ... many lines

def __str__(self):
    if self.parent is None:
        return ('{}'.format(self.name))
    else:
        return ('%s%s%s' % (
            self.parent,
            settings.PARENT_DELIMITER,
            self.name)
        )
```

I only removed the `__str__()` call and added the future directive because the models.py is the first module where it is especially useful. Otherwise you should add `u'` to both format strings here.

It is useful to know what the [python_2_unicode_compatible](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/utils/six/#python_2_unicode_compatible) decorator does. The result of `__str__` method should be `text_type` (unicode in Python 2), but if you call it directly in Python 2 you get `bytes` type. The formatting operator selects the matching method but any explicit method is invalid either in Python 3 or in 2. Non ascii values of different types can not be combined.

Comment: Do you mean `from __future__ import unicode_literals` instead of `absolute_import`?

Comment: @AlexL Fixed the typo. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using [six.text_type](http://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.text_type)?

> `six.text_type`
>
> Type for representing (Unicode) textual data. This is `unicode()` in Python 2 and `str` in Python 3.

**edit**: you don't have to install `six`, as the needed methods are present in `django.utils.six` - thanks @hynekcer for pointing it out

> Six provides simple utilities for wrapping over differences between Python 2 and Python 3. It is intended to support codebases that work on both Python 2 and 3 without modification. six consists of only one Python file, so it is painless to copy into a project.~

Comment: 1+, but `django.utils.six` is a simple subset from six of what is usually useful with Django

Answer (score 0):

According to error message test tries to compare `str` and `unicode` objects. That's not good generally.

```
AssertionError: 'Category 1->Category \xc3\xbc' != u'Category 1->Category \xfc'
```

Try to:

- compare unicode objects: `self.assertEqual(self.cat1, cat_result1)`
- always work with unicode locale even if at a moment you are using only latin1-symbols

Comment: The problem is that `type(self.cat1)` is `<type 'str'>` which is equivalent to `bytes`, not to unicode.

Comment: Sorry, not sure in this case. I moved to Python3. Some unicode issues are fixed there.